# update metadata of sugar minted collection

Tags: nft, metadata

Hello I launched a collection on solana and minted it but I want to change the royalties any idea how ? I don't want to do it manually

Comment: have you checked metaboss ?

Comment: i saw people talking about it but didn't quite understand how to use it